# Connecting points in space under two conditions

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

In a try to generalize [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426261/looking-for-polyhedra-under-two-simple-but-stringent-conditionts) I came up with the following question:
Is there any number $N$ such that for given $N$ points in space it is possible  to join all of them with paths (each path connects two *different* points) such that:

> Every point is connected by at least 4 paths (i.e., degree of each
>   vertex is bigger than 3) and
>
> for every point the smallest closed loop (i.e., going back to itself)
>   following the paths goes through at least 3 other points and
>
> for any two points there is a series of paths connecting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. An example is afforded by the hypercube graph $Q_4$ on $N=16$ vertices. The Wikipedia article on [hypercube graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) has an illustration of $Q_4$ that makes it easy to check this.

Comment: Well played, sir!